# Return something that isn't element ID with driver.find_elements_by

Tags: python, selenium, appium

I am looking for a list of certain elements of a certain class. However, driver.find_elements_by_locator returns a list of WebElements be default. Since the element ID is changing at every moment, I was wondering whether I could use find_elements_by_locator and return a list of something a bit more constant, like XPATH.

Code:

```
listofblocks = driver1.find_elements_by_class_name("android.widget.RelativeLayout")
print(listofblocks)
```

Nothing doesn't technically work, just looking for a better return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See,

```
driver.find_elements_by_locator
```

where **locator** could be **xpath**, **css**, or **id**, **class**.. etc.

it will always return a **list**, not **element IDs**.

and that list will contains **WebElements** associated with the locator passed.

once you have a list, in your case `listofblocks` , you can iterate it :-

```
for block in listofblocks:
    print(block.text) # this is just an example, you can call any webelement method here.
```

also

```
listofblocks[0]
```

would return first element of the list, so

you can do

`listofblocks[0].click()` or  `listofblocks[0].text`

and so on..

Comment: Point taken, I'll edit this post to clarify on what I want.

Comment: Using print(block.text) gives me an error of "'list' object has no attribute 'text'".

Comment: can you print this also `print(len(listofblocks))`

Answer (score 0):

My answer would depend on what do you want to do with the stuff that you get back.  Using driver.find_elements_by_locator will return a list of WebElements, as you say.  Once you have those elements you can extract whatever information you need from them, assuming that it's there.  Looking for a specific attribute on the element:

```
attr_values = [element.get_attribute('my_attr') for element in listofblocks]
```

You hinted that you may be looking for some unique identifier of the object that won't change.  for that you should discuss with the developers to help identify these things.  You may need to use a combination of class and location.